# Adding JSON Array to already existing JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have an existing JSON file that just contains simple place holder JSON arrays. I would like to be able to add to the specific JSON arrays. Here is my code:

```
List<string> newEvent = new List<string>();
newEvent.Add(msg.Split('|')[1]);
newEvent.Add(msg.Split('|')[2]);
newEvent.Add(msg.Split('|')[3]);
newEvent.Add(msg.Split('|')[4]);
newEvent.Add(msg.Split('|')[5]);
JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("data.json"));
JArray incomingEvents = jsonObject["incomingEvents"].Value<JArray>();
incomingEvents.Add(newEvent);
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(incomingEvents, Formatting.Indented));
```

Which gives me an output to the console of:

```
[
  [
    "eventnumber",
    "time",
    "type",
    "location",
    "summary"
  ],
  "eventNumber",
  "Time",
  "Type",
  "Location",
  "Summary"
]
```

Whereas what I am trying to produce would look more like this:

```
[
  [
    "eventnumber",
    "time",
    "type",
    "location",
    "summary"
  ],
  [
    "eventNumber",
    "Time",
    "Type",
    "Location",
    "Summary"
  ],
]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Show me what is in the data.json and what is in the msg variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your newEvent object to JArray Object before you add to incomingEvents

```
 List<string> newEvent = new List<string>();
        newEvent.Add(msg.Split('|')[1]);
        newEvent.Add(msg.Split('|')[2]);
        newEvent.Add(msg.Split('|')[3]);
        newEvent.Add(msg.Split('|')[4]);
        newEvent.Add(msg.Split('|')[5]);

        JArray newEventJsonItem = new JArray(newEvent);//Convert newEvent to JArray.

        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("data.json"));

        JArray incomingEvents = jsonObject["incomingEvents"].Value<JArray>();

        incomingEvents.Add(newEventJsonItem );//Insert new JArray object.

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(incomingEvents, Formatting.Indented));
```